# Why isn't this flexbox code displaying half of my checkboxes in each of the child div elements in my container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get two groups of checkboxes to display side by side in my parent flex container to make more room for some additional elements on my webpage.  I have coded it per below and following the training on had on flex but I'm obviously missing something.  When this area of my page is displayed, it is still just a vertical column with all of the checkboxes instead of two groups side my side.  Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#larryfoto {
  max-width: 90px;
}

#brochure {
  max-width: 70px;
}

.headertd {
  width: 34%;
}

#socialcontainer {
  padding: 20px;
}

#headerlogo {
  width: 85%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#fb {
  width: 33%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#linkedin {
  width: 33%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#ig {
  width: 33%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#warrantywisdom {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-rignt: auto;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=radio] label {}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
}

#bodydiv {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#headerdiv {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.warranty_option_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wty_option_child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.toolbox {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#inputcell {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#radiocell {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#contactinfocell {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  background-image: url('hwa_house_bkgrnd.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

form {
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#myImg2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg2:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption2 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerdiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="headertd"><img src="hwa_header.jpg" id="headerlogo"></td>
      <td class="headertd"><img src="header2.jpg" id="headerlogo2"></td>
      <td id="socialcontainer">
        <td class="socialtd" id="socialcell">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100008339314922"><img src="fb.png" id="fb"></td>
        <td class="socialtd">
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/larry-hines-66a8a21/"><img src="linkedin.png" id="linkedin"></td>
        <td class="socialtd">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lwhmicrovision/"><img src="ig.png" id="ig"></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<div id="bodydiv">

    <form class="input-form" name="textinput" id="input_form" method="POST">
      <table id="formtable">
        <tr id="mainrow">
          <td id="inputcell">


            <label for="propertyaddress">Covered Property Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="propertyaddress" name="propertyaddress" required>
            <label for="mailingaddress">Mailing Address (If Different)</label>
            <input type="text" id="mailingaddress" name="mailingaddress">
            <label for="buyername">Buyer Name(s)</label>
            <input type="text" id="buyername" name="buyername" required>
            <label for="buyeremail">Buyer Email Address</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="buyeremail" name="buyeremail" required><br>
            <label for="buyerphone">Buyer Phone</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="buyerphone" name="buyerphone"><br>
            <label for="titlecompany">Title Company</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="titlecompany" name="titlecompany"><br>
            <label for="escrowofficer">Escrow Officer Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="escrowofficer" name="escrowofficer"><br>
            <label for="escrowofficeremail">Escrow Officer Email Address</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="escrowofficeremail" name="escrowofficeremail"><br>
            <label for="escrowofficerphone">Escrow Officer Phone</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="escrowofficerphone" name="escrowofficerphone"><br>
            <label for="referringagent">Agent Name and Agency</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="referringagent" name="referringagent" required><br>
            <label for="referringagentphone">Agent Phone</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="referringagentphone" name="referringagentphone" required><br>
            <label for="referringagentemail">Agent Email Address</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="referringagentemail" name="referringagentemail" required><br>
          </td>

          <td id="radiocell">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label for="closingdate"><u>Closing Date</u></label><br>
                  <input type="date" id="closingdate" name="closingdate" required><br><br>
                  <label for="hometype"><u>Type of Home</u></label><br><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Single Family" name="hometype" value="singlefamily" required><label for="Single Family">Single Family</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home" name="hometype" value="towncondomobile"><label for="Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home">Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home</label><br>
                  <select form="input_form" name="multitype" id="duplex_triplex_fourplex" value="Multi-Flat Warranty Options">
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Multi-Flat Option</option>
                    <option value="duplex_gold">Duplex Gold - $720</option>
                    <option value="duplex_platinum">Duplex Platinum - $855</option>
                    <option value="duplex_diamond">Duplex Diamond - $945</option>
                    <option value="triplex_gold">Triplex Gold - $1040</option>
                    <option value="triplex_platinum">Triplex Platinum - $1235</option>
                    <option value="triplex_gold">Triplex Diamond - $1365</option>
                    <option value="triplex_gold">Fourplex Gold - $1360</option>
                    <option value="triplex_platinum">Fourplex Platinum - $1615</option>
                    <option value="triplex_gold">Fourplex Diamond - $1785</option>
                  </select>


                </td>
                <td>
                  <label for="warrantytype"><u>Select Warranty Type</u></label><br><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="warrantytype" value="Gold" required><label for="Gold">Gold - $400</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Platinum" name="warrantytype" value="Platinum"><label for="Platinum">Platinum - $475</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Diamond" name="warrantytype" value="Diamond"><label for="Diamond">Diamond - $525</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Sellers" name="warrantytype" value="Sellers"><label for="Sellers">Sellers Warranty</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="New Construction" name="warrantytype" value="New Construction"><label for="New Construction">New Construction</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" id="Multiyear" name="warrantytype" value="Multi-Year"><label for="Multiyear">Multi-Year Warranty</label><br><br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <label for="warrantynotes" title="Describe warranty type if new construction or multi-year, also please note if warranty to be paid by proceeds at closing or directly by buyer, seller or real estate agent"><u>Warranty Notes - (hover mouse over this label for instructions)</u></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="notes" name="warrantynotes"><br>

            <label for="options"><u>Options</u></label><br>

            <div class="warranty_option_container">
              <div class="wty_option_child">
                <input type="checkbox" id="greenplus" name="optiontype[]" value="greenplus"><label for="greenplus">$70 Green Plus</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="termite" name="optiontype[]" value="termite"><label for="termite">$75 Subterranean Termite Treatment</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="freezer" name="optiontype[]" value="freezer"><label for="freezer">$50 Freezer-Standalone</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wetbar" name="optiontype[]" value="wetbar"><label for="wetbar">$25 Wet Bar Refrigerator/2nd Fridge</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="poolspa" name="optiontype[]" value="poolspa"><label for="poolspa">$150 Pool/Spa Combo</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="addpoolspa" name="optiontype[]" value="addpoolspa"><label for="addpoolspa">$150 Additional Pool or Spa</label>
              </div>

              <div class="wty_option_child">
                <input type="checkbox" id="saltpool" name="optiontype[]" value="saltpool"><label for="saltpool">$300 Salt Water Pool w/Spa Combo</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wellpump" name="optiontype[]" value="wellpump"><label for="wellpump">$100 Well Pump</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="septicpump" name="optiontype[]" value="septicpump"><label for="septicpump">$75 Septic /Ejector Pump/Tank Pumping</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="waterline" name="optiontype[]" value="waterline"><label for="waterline">$90 External Water Line Repair</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="waterlineandsewer" name="optiontype[]" value="waterlineandsewer"><label for="waterlineandsewer">$195 External Water/Sewer Line Repair</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <input type="text" id="sendername" name="sendername" required value="Enter Your Name Here"><br>
            <input type="text" id="orderemail" name="orderemail" required value="Enter Your Email Address"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="placeorder" name="placeorder" style="width:100%;" value="Place Warranty Order"><br><br> *Payment is not required at time of order. You will receive an invoice after the order is placed. Contact me to discuss payment
            options.


          </td>

          <td id="contactinfocell" class="toolbox">
            <h2>Warranty Toolbox</h2>
            <hr>

            <table>
              <tr>
                <td id="warrantycell">


                  <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
                  <img id="myImg" src="updated_warranty_matrix.jpg" alt="Warranty Option Matrix" style="width:100%;max-width:110px"><br> View Warranty Options
                  <!-- The Modal -->
                  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                    <!-- The Close Button -->
                    <span class="close" id="close">&times;</span>

                    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

                    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                    <div id="caption"></div>

                  </div>
                  <script>
                    // Get the modal
                    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

                    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
                    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
                    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
                    img.onclick = function() {
                      modal.style.display = "block";
                      modalImg.src = this.src;
                      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                    }

                    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                    span.onclick = function() {
                      modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                  </script>
                  <br>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
                  <img id="myImg2" src="file_claim.jpg" alt="File a Claim" style="width:100%;max-width:125px"><br> File a Claim

                  <!-- The Modal -->
                  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                    <!-- The Close Button -->
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>

                    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img02">

                    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                    <div id="caption2"></div>

                  </div>
                  <script>
                    // Get the modal
                    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");

                    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                    var img = document.getElementById("myImg2");
                    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
                    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption2");
                    img.onclick = function() {
                      modal.style.display = "block";
                      modalImg.src = this.src;
                      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                    }

                    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

                    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                    span.onclick = function() {
                      modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                  </script>
                </td>

                <td "brochurecell">
                  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1txuozSp-8iqtVryAHcP1qMLERDxwIDA4/view?usp=sharing"><img src="brochure_thumb.jpg" width="70" height="95" id="brochure"></a><br>Brochure

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td id="warrantywisdom" class="toolbox">
                  <ul class="doubleBullets">
                    <u><b>Watch our Warranty Wisdom Videos to get the most from your home warranty!</b></u><br><br>
                    <ul class="doubleBullets">
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/about-hwa-home-warranty-coverage-video">Understand HWA Home Warranty Coverage</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/home-warranty-vs-homeowners-insurance-video">Home Warranty vs. Homeowners Insurance - What's the Difference?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/why-choose-hwa-video">Why Choose HWA</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/who-we-are-video">Home Warranty of America (HWA): Who We Are</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/choosing-coverage-video">How Do I Know What Coverage I Need for My Home Warranty?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="doubleBullets">
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/what-is-covered-video">What's Covered by an HWA Home Warranty?</a></li>

                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/file-a-claim-video">How Do I File a Claim with Home Warranty of America?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.hwahomewarranty.com/learning-center/videos/claim-rejection-video">Why Was My Claim Rejected?</a></li>
                    </ul><br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td id="contactme" class="toolbox">
                  <u><b>Contact Me</b></u><br><br> Larry Hines<br> Account Executive, Idaho<br> Home Warranty of America<br> (208) 761-1666<br>
                  <a href="mailto:larry.hines@hwahomewarranty.com">larry.hines@hwahomewarranty.com</a>
                </td>
                <td><img src="larry_bc_photo.jpg" id="larryfoto">
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
            <hr>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td id="promotext">
                  <h2>Check out our new<br>Spring Promo!</h2>
                </td>
                <td width="100px;">
                  <img src="arrow.png" style="width:100%; max-width:80px;">
                </td>
                <td id="arlocell">
                  <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
                  <img id="myImg3" src="arlo_thumbnail.JPG" alt="Spring Promo" style="width:100%;max-width:80px;"><br>

                  <!-- The Modal -->
                  <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

                    <!-- The Close Button -->
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>

                    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img03">

                    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                    <div id="caption3"></div>

                  </div>
                  <script>
                    // Get the modal
                    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal3");

                    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                    var img = document.getElementById("myImg3");
                    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img03");
                    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption3");
                    img.onclick = function() {
                      modal.style.display = "block";
                      modalImg.src = "HWA_Arlo_flyer.jpg";
                      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                    }

                    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];

                    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                    span.onclick = function() {
                      modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                  </script>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </tr>
      </table>

      </td>
      </tr>

      </table>

    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the whole .CSS file.  I don't see anything competing but it's worth mentioning that the container and child div's in my flexbox are all inside of a  element that is part of a 3 column table that lays out the format of the page.  Does flexbox work inside of a TD?

Comment: I put your code into an executable snippet and it appears to work. Please be sure to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. I'm guessing you have more CSS that could be causing the issue.

Comment: I just ran it on here and it worked as well.  I'll post the whole .css file to see if there is something else interfering with the styling of my flexbox.  I'm still pretty new to this so wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Here is the whole CSS file

Comment: Try adding flex shrink 0 to your flex items

Comment: You should post all code to reproduce period, not just CSS. People shouldn't be poking around eyeballing your problem. Give the code that produces the problem so people can help debug it.

Comment: While `<td>` elements don't need to be closed (since they're implicitly closed when either a `</tr>` or `<td>` head is encountered), it seems odd that you have one that is uniquely unclosed. Though it seems you were trying to wrap other `<td>` elements within it, which is impossible, unless they themselves are nested within a `<table>`.

Comment: Huangism - flex-shrink: 0; didn't work.

Comment: David says reinstate Monica - I added the missing </td> but nothing changed.  I have looked elsewhere to see if flexbox works inside of table cells and can't really find anything